# Invalid CFBundleIdentier ITMS-90376

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, watchkit, cfbundleidentifier

In my Xcode(7.2) Project (Watchkit and IOS app), I am getting an error when trying to submit a built(using Archive upload) of my app to Itunes connect via Xcode that looks like:

```
ERROR ITMS-90376 "Invalid CFBundlerIdentifier. The CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.MYCOMPANY.MY-APP' 
of watch application 'MY-APP.app/Watch/MY APP Watchkit App.app' does not properly 
extend the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.MYCOMPANY.MY-APP' of its containing 
iOS application."
```

There are are a few things I want(not necessarily in this order):

1. What is the difference between CFBundleIdentifier and the Application bundle Identifier?
2. Where can I find the CFBundleIdentifier?
3. What does this error mean?
4. How can I fix this error?

Edit: I forgot to mention that it also gave me a second warning:

```
iTunes operation succeeded with a warning.
The resulting API analysis file is too large We were unable to validate your API usage
```

I tried looking for people had the same error(no luck there).
Then I tried looking for people with similar errors(did not solve my problem).

If you need any more information: **Just Ask Me**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CFBundleIdentifier` is the `Core Foundation Key` and `Bundle Identifier` is its `Xcode` name for the same key that you can find in Info.plist file of your project.

[More about Core Foundation Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html)

In watch app there is particular format to follow for you bundle identifiers for the iOS app, watch app and the extension.

1. iOS App Target (**Bundle Identifier** : com.companyName.AppName)
2. WatchKit App Target (**Bundle Identifier** : com.companyName.AppName.watchkitapp)
3. WatchKit Extension Target (**Bundle Identifier** : com.companyName.AppName.watchkitapp.watchkitextension)

If you see watch app target contains the companion app bundle identifier  as prefix followed by **watchkitapp** and watch kit extension target contains watch kit app bundle identifier as prefix followed **watchkitextension**.

All you need is to set proper identifiers in each of target's plist file .

[Here is a complete tutorial to submit a watch app](http://basememara.com/submitting-apple-watch-apps-to-the-app-store/)

Comment: Thank you so much I will look inside my .plist files and look for any different identifiers. Ill tell you if it works. And thank  you for the tutorial

Comment: Dude, you are a LIFESAVER. I have had this problem for such a long time. All it took was you. Thank you so much man. My problem  was I gave wrong identifiers to the plists. They were similar, just wrong.